# Unable to start cluster after upgrading th Databricks premium - ssh error

Tags: azure, ssh, databricks, azure-databricks

I recently upgraded our workspace to Premium tier, and am now unable to start a cluster. The workspace is deployed on a private VNet, and is not connected to an on-prem network. The subnets are connected correctly.

The following error is received:

`Instances Unreachable: Resources were not reachable via SSH. If the problem persists, this usually indicates a network environment misconfiguration. Please check your cloud provider configuration, and make sure that Databricks control plane can reach Spark clusters instances.`

This seems to be an issue with the VNet configuration, but I cannot find the issue. Are there any steps I need to take after upgrading to a premium workspace to remove this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found: The old network security groups needed to be dislocated from the subnets. After disconnecting the old NSGs the error was resolved.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade from standard to premium SKU seems to be a mess when done through the UI. It is recommended to upgrade via the ARM Template. It will go much smoother.